# Custom Soundcloud visualizer webgl

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, soundcloud

I've been looking through the soundcloud documentation and trying to find a way to create a visualizer for soundcloud tracks.  The problem is that in order to create a proper visualizer, I need access to the source waveform.  I would imagine that this isn't directly available because this could cause copyright issues.  However, I did find this [visualizer](http://www.apexvj.com/hd/player?s=83742832) but it uses flash.  I also saw that mr doob had [a different visualizer](http://soundcloud.com/apps/comments-visualizer), but his only visualized comments.

So my question is: is there a way to get access to the waveform through the soundcloud api so that I can visualize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Web Audio API to get current frequencies in order to visualize them: http://themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2012/09/18/